# React JS URL Error - "./pages/test.js Module not found: 'https://....../example.json' in '/home/Desktop/App/pages"

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing, shopify

For some reason, when I assign a .json URL file to a variable in React using the following code

```
var data = require('https://.....long-URL-here.../checkouts.json');
```

It gives an error

```
./pages/test.js Module not found:  'https://....../checkouts.json' in '/home/Desktop/App/pages'
```

To me it seems like it is attempting to input a URL as a library, but I am not sure how to code it. I am new to JS and React but not to coding in general, and not sure whether it is actually possible - how could I import the JSON to be iterated over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the right way to include JSON. If you want to read JSON from a remote URL, you need to get it via HTTP request. You can use something like [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). A sample code to fetch a publicly available JSON file will look like below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shopify/shopify-app-node/master/package.json"
      );
      const parsed = await response.json();
      setData(parsed);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Sandbox Link for Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-get-json-from-remote-url-vydjy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thanks for the help! What would need to happen if it was accessing a private JSON, with a user/pass for api connections?